# Sony xperia ringtone

Tags: ringtone, default-applications

I am using this mobile for over a week now and accidentally, I tapped on open (always open) on my ringtone such that, now I cannot set any MP3 ringtones and stuck with default Sony ringtones.

Is there anyway that I can change it to use MP3 ringtones.

Comment: Which Sony Xperia? What version of Android?

Comment: You opened the ringtone with what app? Can you improve the clarity of language?

Comment: Have you tried to go to *Settings->Apps->Manage Apps*, scroll to the app you made default, open its entry, and tap the 'clear defaults' button?

Answer (score 0):

Almost every Android file manager or music player has option to set song (not only `mp3`) as ringtone - so just use it. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyDM9YqDr0A) may be helpful.